# If a surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ passes the vertical line test, is $S$ necessarily the graph of some function?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, functions

I understand that for single output functions in the $x$, $y$ plane, the vertical line test is used to check if a given curve is a valid function. But if we implement the vertical line test in 3-space, does that mean we necessarily have a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the same logic extends to higher dimensions.

The reasoning behind the vertical line test is to check if there are any other points in the graph which correspond to the same $x-$value but a different $y-$value. A function is just a map between two sets which maps each member of the domain to a single member of the codomain, so as long as there is no $x-$value which maps to multiple $y-$values, the map is a function.

So similarly, if you look at a graph in $3$ dimensions as a map from ordered $(x,y)$ pairs to $z-$values, as long as no pair of $x$ and $y-$values map to multiple $z-$values, the map is again a function. This can be represented the same way visually by dragging a vertical line through the surface.